# Ruby on Rails form_for reference class id and pass to child comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class called "questions", which is similar to an article, and each of them can have comments. Now the problem is, that I want to show multiple questions on the index page and all displaying the comments of the specific question as well as a small little form to leave a comment, which should be added to its question. Basically I have added the form and done everything, apart from figuring out how to get the question id and pass it to the comment.

I have made a little screenshot as well: http://prntscr.com/2pjk0i

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /questions
# GET /questions.json
def index
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  @questions = Question.all
end

# GET /questions/1
# GET /questions/1.json
def show
end

# GET /questions/new
def new
  @question = Question.new
end

# GET /questions/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /questions
# POST /questions.json
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])

  @question.update(:user_id => @current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.save
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @question }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /questions/1
# PATCH/PUT /questions/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @question.update(question_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /questions/1
# DELETE /questions/1.json
def destroy
  @question.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to questions_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])

    @comment.update(:user_id => @current_user.id, :question_id => ?) # What to add here to get the specific question id? 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/', notice: 'comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to '', notice: 'comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to '' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Listing questions</h1>

<%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path %>

<hr>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>

  <!-- Author -->
  <%= question.user.name %> <br>

  <!-- Date -->
  <%= question.created_at %> <br>

  <!-- Title -->
  <%= question.title %> <br>

  <!-- Body -->
  <%= question.body %> <br>

  <%= question.id %> <br>

  <!-- Comment count -->
  <%= question.comments.size %> Comment <br>

  <!-- Comments -->
  <% question.comments.each do |comment| %>

    <!-- Comment Author -->
    <%= comment.user.name %> <br>

    <!-- Comment Date -->
    <%= comment.created_at %> <br>

    <!-- Comment Body -->
    <%= comment.body %> <br>

  <% end %>

  <%= form_for(question.comments.new) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <hr>

<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

The form_for will need to submit the question_id somehow - either by a route or through the form.  I recommend a route.

If you don't interact with comments independently - if there is always a question, then change your routes to something like this:

```
resources :questions do
  resources :comments
end
```

Then - in your form for, you will do this

```
<%= form_for [question, question.comments.new] do |f| %>
```

This will cause the form to submit (POST) to /question/:question_id/comments and you can handle it from there.

In the comments controller - you'll get the question from the params[:question_id] and return the result via an ajax response (respond to json).

This part is still tricky if you haven't done it before.  If you need help with that part, you can probably find good examples or ask a separate question...

Comment: I would argue that you should not call `question.comments.new` from the view, and should instead initialize it from the controller and pass it to the view.  My argument assumes you are doing a true form submission, and if there are validation errors, you want to show the form with what the user entered on the prior page rather than wiping it clean with another new question instance.

Comment: Considering the screen shot with many forms showing - one per question - the forms are probably remote => true and the errors would be handled with the json response, or with the html rendered ajax response.

Comment: I gave it a try, but it also does not work and no id is passed at all :-/

Comment: Look at the HTML source.  The form should have the correct URL.  When you click the form, it should hit the expected controller and action (you can see this in the logs) and you should be able to access the params in the action.  If the id is not there, it's not coming correctly from the form.  If you are nesting this resource - the form action should be something like "/questions/:question_id/comments".

Answer (score 1):

you can add hidden field inside your form

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id %>
```

or you can change your form

```
<%= form_for :comment, :url => comments_path(question_id:question.id) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :body %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

when u submit this form u will have url like /comments?question_id=id